# How to add one more action to unknownContentType dialog?

Tags: firefox-addon

In case user downloads particular type of file (let's say .doc), I should show one more item (i.e. possible action) in addition to Save and Open at [unknownContentType](http://chrome://mozapps/content/downloads/unknownContentType.xul) Firefox dialog.

How can I do it?

**Upd.** Looking at FlashGot addon sources, I've extracted the following:

**chrome.manifest**

```
overlay chrome://mozapps/content/downloads/unknownContentType.xul chrome://flashgot/content/DMOverlayFx.xul
overlay chrome://global/content/nsHelperAppDlg.xul chrome://flashgot/content/DMOverlayMoz.xul
```

Why do they have two overlays? What second does? And, how to understand that user chosen my option?

**DMOverlayFx.xul**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<overlay id="DMOverlayFF" 
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

<script type="application/x-javascript" src="Common.js"/>
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="DMOverlay.js"/>

  <radiogroup id="mode" >
        <vbox insertbefore="save" id="synoextcontainer" flex="1">
            <hbox flex="1">
        <radio id="synoext-dmradio" label="Download with Synology NAS" />

            </hbox>
        </vbox>
  </radiogroup>
 </overlay>
```

**DMOverlayMoz.xul**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<overlay id="DMOverlayMoz" 
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

<script type="application/x-javascript" src="Common.js"/>
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="DMOverlay.js"/>

  <radiogroup id="mode" >
        <hbox position="3" >
      <radio id="synoext-dmradio" label="Download with Synology NAS"/>

    </hbox>
    </radiogroup>

</overlay>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important file to overlay is unknownContentType.xul. You can see an example here: http://code.google.com/p/firedownload/source/browse/chrome/content/unknownContentType-overlay.xul. This adds a new checkbox to the dialog, but you can use the same approach to add a new radio button. You'll want to include a new JS file in the overlay (like unknownContentType-overlay.js in this example) where you can override the standard processing of the radio buttons. Process your new option and hand off the other options to the existing implementation (look at helperApps.js to see how the standard processing works).

Comment: Thanks, Matthew. Is there any more simple example? I just need to add the radio button (actually, I already did it) and if user chosen that - run my function (now I don't quite understand how to do this).